VsCode：why local path and remote path show different
vscode version: 1.85.2
local os version: macOS  13.5.2
remote os version: linux x86_64 4.19
now, mac is local, source control changes file shows relative path
enter image description here
but, remote shows absolute path, and if open file in changes, window title shows absolute path
enter image description here
I make sure window.title are same in all settings: ${activeFolderMedium}${separator}${rootName}
Now, I want all to use relative path
